# Cannot register iOS device on apple developer

Tags: ios

I'm new to iOS development. I need to register a new iPad with my apple developer account.
When I login to [Apple Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/deviceList.action) the and going into Devices -> All the plus button is disabled even though it say "You can register 59 additional devices"

Comment: Seems like your account does not have enough right to add devices.

Comment: Is it an individual account?

Answer (score 2):

As we know According to information provided by `Apple`.

You are allowed to register up to `100 iOS` devices for testing and Ad Hoc` distribution per membership year. Please Note: Although you may remove a device from your account, it will continue to count against your 100 device limit.

So i think you need to contact your `Team Agent`/`Team Admin` for required permission as your account do't have the permission for adding or removing devices. for ensuring you can check using itunes account this will show the details about user access as like this image shown and 
what i think last your account roles is `read-only access`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the help.
At the end the problem was that I had to reset the devices list to add another device.
It was not so clear because of the message that state I can add 59 additional devices.

After complete the reset process I was able to add the device.

Answer (score 1):

This is Because you are not having complete Authentication. You will have to ask and get Administrative permission from the Developer Account Owner. You must be presently Using a Company/Team Account account.